# Translating flash info box into coordinates for html5 canvas shape?

Tags: html, flash, canvas, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to recreate some flash shapes that appear on rollover upon a circle symbol. I'm needing to convert flash x and y points to the canvas coordinate grid. I figured out how to convert the circle coord points. However, the info I'm given for the shapes that appear on rollover make no sense to me.

For example, take this rollover point, where the dimensions refer to the registration point (little cross in the upper left):

[image: Rollover point]

x = 532.30 
y = 30.35
w/h = 19.80

But based off this, the info I get for the rectangle that appears on rollover makes no sense:

[image: rollover rectange]

x = -7.30
y = 17.30
w = 29.0
h = 16.5

I figured this meant that the rectangle's upper left point was 7.30 pixels to the left, and 17.30 pixels down from the registration point of the circle. Is that right? What origin are these x and y coordinates based off of?

The width and height are completely confusing to me though. The given width is 29.0, but this can't be right. If I get x and y coordinates just using my cursor, its clear that the rectangle is much wider than this:

[image: width 1]
[image: width2]

564 - 521 = 43

43 != 29

Please help me understand the mysterious info box I'm being presented with for this rectangle. I just need to get some vanilla coordinates for it so I can draw it on the HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What origin are these x and y coordinates based off of?

These x and y coordinates are based off of the registration point of *tab* button.

> 43 != 29

When you work with symbols on a stage, the symbols that you're working with aren't the actual original Library symbol. They're copies that can be manipulated by scaling them, applying color and opacity effects and...

This instance of *tab* button is scaled, if you open library panel and edit tab symbol you can see the actual size.

---

**UPDATE**

[image]
[image]

after I change width and height of tab button to 19.80:
[image]
[image]

29*(150/100)=43.5

Comment: I'm asking about the green rectangle around VIEW, not the tab symbol itself.  It appears when you hover over the tab button, and is not a symbol in the library. I don't care about actual size, only about being able to plot all the shapes on the same coordinate plane. I need to figure out its coordinates relative to the same grid that the button is on. So, x=525 ,y=47.65 h=?, w=?

Comment: @two7s_clash, w=43 and you can measure height in the same way (with mouse cursor)

Comment: Hmmm. Some way not to have to do that? Was hoping to reach the answer through math and info that Flash can provide me. Measuring using the mouse cursor seems terribly imprecise.

Comment: @two7s_clash, why downvote? if you want use math, h=h*ScaleHeight(from transform panel). if you want use info panel, create a copy from the button, replace frame 1 and 2(up and over), then rightclick and breakApart.

Comment: More like a "wrong vote," which I corrected. Can you say more about ScaleHeight?

Comment: thanks :). select tab button and open transform panel. there are two numbers in percentage (scaleWidth & scaleHeight).

Comment: Okay, still totally confused, as these are both set at 100%. 100% of 29 is 29, but this rectangle definitely isn't 29 pixels wide. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37207/discussion-between-two7s-clash-and-null-point3r)